# class= btn btn-danger align horizontal

Tags: css

How do I align my 3 buttons horizontal side by side? I think it looks bad as it is now.

```
class= btn btn-danger
```

How do I write the css for that?

my code

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>Stationær & bærbar reparationer</h3>
            <p>Vi kan udskifte alle typer hardware de mest almindelige reparationer omfatter</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">LÆS MERE</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>Fjernelse af virus</h3>
            <p>Hvis din computer er inficeret med virus kan vi hjælpe dig med at rense ud i dit system. Vi kan herudover også hjælpe dig med at sikre dit system mod kommende virus angreb.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">LÆS MERE</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>Data recovery</h3>
            <p>Hvis din harddisk er defekt skifter vi den billigt og hurtigt, vi kan genskabe dine data tilbage i de fleste tilfælde. eller hvis Windows er gået ned, kan vi også redde din data. </p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">LÆS MERE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: SERVICE PC picture]

Answer (score 0):

Two options.

Add css to give h3 and p element fixed height (adjust numbers)

```
.col-sm-4 p {
    height: 200px;
}
.col-sm-4 h3 {
    height: 50px;
}
```

OR
Extract buttons to a new row.

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>Stationær & bærbar reparationer</h3>
            <p>Vi kan udskifte alle typer hardware de mest almindelige reparationer omfatter</p> 
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>Fjernelse af virus</h3>
            <p>Hvis din computer er inficeret med virus kan vi hjælpe dig med at rense ud i dit system. Vi kan herudover også hjælpe dig med at sikre dit system mod kommende virus angreb.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <h3>Data recovery</h3>
            <p>Hvis din harddisk er defekt skifter vi den billigt og hurtigt, vi kan genskabe dine data tilbage i de fleste tilfælde. eller hvis Windows er gået ned, kan vi også redde din data. </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">LÆS MERE</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">LÆS MERE</a>
        </div>
        <div class="col-sm-4">
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger">LÆS MERE</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Edit: Adding code

Comment: I know it maybe to much to ask

but could you give an example how to make a now row, and how the css will look for that please

Comment: Thanks so much for the help, looks very good now using h3 and p element fixed height :)

Comment: Be careful with that though. The css will change the height of all h3 and p elements in col-sm-4 class. You can add one more class to the parent element and then retarget the elements to apply styles.

Side note: Please upvote/accept the answer if you found it useful. Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks you i saw that, and now only use col-sm-4 class for these div. :)

Answer (score 0):

but i see that not the way to do it, if i should use that class again, i may have to add one more class to the parent element and retarget it as you said, just need to figure out how :) i am just a noob and pretty new at this.

but it looks good so far i think

[My new PC service site](http://i62.tinypic.com/2qs5ms2.jpg)